# Alternative proof for dominated convergence theorem without using Fatou's lemma?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

The conclusion of dominated convergence theorem is that $||f-f_n||_{L^1}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. After showing that $f_n\to f\in L^1$, why is it not possible to use the continuity of norm in order to show $\lim_{n\to\infty}||f-f_n||_{L^1}=||\lim_{n\to\infty}(f-f_n)||_{L^1}=0$ instead of applying Fatou's lemma?

Comment: The norm is only continuous with respect to itself. It is in general *not* continuous with respect to pointwise convergence. Nor is norm convergence immediate once you have shown $f_n \to f$ pointwise and that $\int f_n d \mu \to \int f d \mu$. However, once you have shown that $f_n \to f$ in the $L^1$ topology, it immediately follows that $f_n - f \to 0$ in the $L^1$ topology.

Comment: Thanks for your remark! But sorry for confusion. When I wrote "after showing that $f_n\to f\in L^1$", I meant that "after showing that $f\in L^1$ where $f_n\to f$ pointwisely. So, probably there isn't any simplistic proof without Fatou's lemma.

Comment: The other main proof that I know proves the Vitali Convergence Theorem and checks that the LDCT hypotheses imply the VCT hypotheses. Anyway no, it is still not true that if $f_n$ are integrable, $f$ is integrable, $f_n \to f$ pointwise, then $f_n \to f$ in the $L^1$ topology. The usual examples of this have $f=0$ (which is obviously integrable), for instance using $f_n=n \chi_{(0,1/n)}$.